# why slider height is not decreasing as browser size decreases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have plugin which is working fine but when the browser size(changes) decreases, the width of images is decreasing as per browser screen size but height of image is not decreasing.

Following is the code:

```
 <div id="smart-gallery">
        <a href="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg" title="First Image">
            <img src="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg" /></a> 

            <a href="images/cubagallery-img-2.jpg"
                title="Second Image">
                <img src="images/cubagallery-img-2.jpg" /></a> <a href="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg"
                    title="Third Image">
                    <img src="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg" /></a> <a href="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg"
                        title="Fourth Image">
                        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg" /></a> <a href="images/cubagallery-img-5.jpg"
                            title="Fifth Image">
                            <img src="images/cubagallery-img-5.jpg" /></a> 
    </div>
```

Following is css for above code..

```
.min-gallery
{
    max-width: 1400px;
    height: 630px;
    margin: auto;
}
.min-gallery .preview
{
    max-width: 1300px;
    height: 493px;
    margin-top: 36px;
    margin-left: 36px;
    margin-right: 36px;
    position: relative;

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: White;
}
```

In above both class i changed width to max-width and because of this image size changes as per browser screen size. But height of image is not changing, it is fixed. 
For this I changed the property, height to max-height at that time the image is getting vanished(means image height becoming 0px). And when it changed to min-height, the image height is not increasing when browser screen size is increased.

I did Google very much but I am not getting how to resolve this issue.
Please can anyone help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to use height:100% with the div ? because that doesn't work sometimes .. try applying the height on each img

Comment: @CME64: Height 100% doesn't work

Comment: are you sure this css is for the same html code ? because I can't see those classes anywhere within !

Comment: @CME64 yes it is applying from js

Comment: then please add that js that you have, to help people help you

Answer (score 0):

Make in the class .min gallary also a max height instead of a normal height, I think that should fix it.

```
  .min-gallery{ max-width: 1400px;
max-height: 630px;
margin: auto;
```

}